# How do I create forms using Geodatabase's related tables in ArcPad Studio 10?

Tags: arcmap, arcgis-10.0, mobile, arcpad

I have a Geodatabase with a Points table and number of related tables. The reason for the related tables is because of the large number of fields.  The relationships are reconginsed by ArcGIS and ArcPad Studio OK.
I'm trying to generate a number of forms based on this Geodatabase. A form is automatically created for me using the primary (points) table in ArcPad Studio, but the related tables are only shown in the Attribute tab.

I have tried to create a forum using the "Related Tables" button, thinking I could call this form using a button on the main form.  So on the main form I've placed a VBScript code to say `frmChild.Show`.  Where frmChild is based on the related tables. But this gives me an error saying `Object doesn't support this action`.

Any one have any idea what how I can create from using related tables and display them?

Thanks

Comment: My problem is that despite using the **ArcPad Data Manager** to checkout a filedatabase Feature Class, no AXFs are created. any ideas? Thanks Jorge

Answer (score 3):

Not a problem!! Creating forms for related tables in ArcPad Studio is very straightforward after checking out your data from ArcMap using the ArcPad data manager to create an .axf...

From the tree view of you .axf in ArcPad Studio, double-click on the feature class that has related tables to open the dialogue. This will enable the "Forms" button on the main toolbar (the one that looks like two forms, hover mouse for tooltips).

This will open a new dialog - highlight the "EDITFORM / Feature class" name row in the table to enable the "Related Tables" button. This will bring up a list of the tables related to the feature class. Double-click the name of the table to edit/customize the form!!

Hope this helps!!

Comment: Thanks Hannah, I have done this, however I still get an error while completing the related table form (as a user in ArcPad). The feature table an the related tables have a relationship between a primary key that is entered manually by the user in the feature table.  This is the foreign key in the related table.  I error I get is "A foreign key value cannot be inserted because a correcponding primary ley value does not exist".  Not sure how I'm suppost to handle this. Should the feature table be saved first before the related table? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Going back to your geodatabase, if you set your "Primary Key" field as required and enter this value on your forms BEFORE moving to the related table forms there should not be a problem. ArcPad is specifically engineered to save the Parent data when you attempt to enter Child data, so this is not the issue. If you look at the "Poles" dataset in the "Riverside" sample data that is supplied with ArcPad, it will give you a better understanding of how related tables perform in ArcPad.

Let me know how you get on!!

- Hannah Ferrier

Comment: Thanks I'll try this, but ArcPad feels like an unfinished product. I have another desperate query and will post as another question.

Answer (score 0):

Just to pick up on your point re: ArcPad feeling like an unfinished product - ArcPad has been around for 10 years now and the release of ArcPad 10 has had substantial development improvements including drawing, photos, incorporating ArcGIS Online etc. If you have any ideas on how to improve ArcPad for future releases, please visit http://ideas.arcgis.com/ and follow the links to ArcPad.

Hannah Ferrier, Mobile GIS Specialist
Maptel Pty.Ltd.